# sql server 2008: importing data from excel 2003 file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

i have a very simple excel file that i need to import into a table in sql server 2008.

one of the fields is a bit complex and i dont think it can be saved effectively to a csv, since it sometimes has comas and single quotes in it. it screwed up the formatting when i save to a csv. so i would like to try to import directly from the xls file.

does anyone know how to import from xls to sql server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Express, run C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe

Answer (score 2):

try using the sql server management studio

right click in your database -> Tasks -> Import Data..

[image]

check this link for more info

[How to: Run the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

Comment: Check this link http://www.sqlis.com/post/SQL-Server-Editions-and-Integration-Services.aspx

Comment: @jenny: For Express, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894345/sql-server-2008-importing-data-from-excel-2003-file/3894453#3894453).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has an import wizard that works with .xls files.

Answer (score 1):

The import wizard generates an SSIS package for you. If you want more control, you can create the SSIS package yourself in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Integration Services for the win. [Check this out!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)